# I am using nestjs and i came up to this concept : middleware is unaware of the execution context

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Can someone explain what is the meaning of that concept.
what is the execution context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [described in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/execution-context), the `ExecutionContext` is a custom object specific to Nest that is a wrapper around the `ArgumentHost` to capture the context data depending on the transport type (rpc, http, graphql, or websocket) and the class and method that are being called. Enhancers like guards and interceptors are ExecutionContext aware, and as such they can read metadata on the method to determine how to act in specific contexts. The ExceptionFilter, on the other hand, is only ArgumentHost aware, because it is possible to get into the filter without triggering any route (like a 404).

Now for the different transports, they each have their own set up underlying methods to help in getting the metadata about the request:

- http: `context.switchToHttp()` and then there's `getNext`, `getRequest`, and `getResponse` to get the corresponding express or fastify objects/methods
- graphql: You need to pass `context` to `GqlExecutionContext.create()` and then there's `getContext()` and `getInfo()` for more metadata
- rpc: `context.switchToRpc()` and then there's `getContext()` and `getData()`. With `getContext()` you'll get the underlying transport context which has many more helper methods like `getTopic()` or others, **that are each transport specific**
- ws: `context.switchToWs()` and then you have `getClient()` and `getPattern()`

Middleware and pipes are not aware of either the `ExecutionContext` or the `ArgumentHost` and must be built accordingly. As the middleware already has access to the `request` it generally shouldn't be too tough to work around that, so long as you don't need to make use of reflectiopn, and if you do then translate it to a guard or interceptor.

[I have a set of interceptor helpers for my `OgmaInterceptor` that each make use of the `ExecutionContext` and all that it can do if you want to take a look](https://github.com/jmcdo29/ogma/tree/main/packages/nestjs-module/src/interceptor/providers)

Comment: what is the benefit that Pipe are not aware of ExecutionContext ?

Comment: I don't have an answer for that, just stating the facts I know

Comment: The ExceptionFilter, on the other hand, is only ArgumentHost aware  : why you say: is only aware"? if it is aware abount ArgHost it have even the ExecutionContext  can you explain why please???

Comment: `ExecutionContext` is `ArgumentHost` _plus_ `getClass` and `getHandler` methods. Interceptors and Guards are `ExecutionContext` aware. ExceptionFilters are only `ArgumentHost` aware as they don't know what class/method was called, if any, while the error was thrown